# How do I Go to Definition for lambda expressions in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda

I am facing a situation with Visual Studio for Mac 2019, wherein I am not able to go to definition for lambda expressions like `.where` or `.ToList`. It just opens the Assembly Browser. However for C# classes, it does navigate to the definition like for `Console`, `Join`, etc.

My keybindings in Visual Studio look like as attached. Also when I try to edit them to just ⌘D it shows unreadable content.

[image]

Example code:

```
List<Warrior> warriors = new List<Warrior>()
            {
                new Warrior() { Height = 100 },
                new Warrior() { Height = 80 },
                new Warrior() { Height = 100 },
                new Warrior() { Height = 70 },
            };

            List<int> heights = warriors.Where(wh => wh.Height == 100)
                                        .Select(wh => wh.Height)
                                        .ToList();

internal class Warrior
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Comment: Does anybody have answer to this?

Comment: Kindly look into this as its very trying to search for each lambda expression in Google instead of Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: Strange nobody has the answer to this question. Will close it.

Comment: Not a lot of people probably saw this because you originally only tagged this with [lambda]. There are tags for [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) and for [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), and people here tend to follow specific tags to answer, especially at least 1 programming language tag. See [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). I have edited your post to add the proper tags.

Comment: Also you cannot always expect "*a timely response*" since Stack Overflow is not your personal help desk. It is meant to be a long-term Q&A, so you never know when you'll get an answer. See [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/2745495).